# jQuery insert child into element at set index

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to use jQuery to insert an html element inside another element and at a particular position.

I've found a way I can do it in Javascript but was wondering if there's a shorter 'one line of code' way of doing it in jQuery.

```
var container = document.getElementById("container");
container.insertBefore( html, container.children[0] );
```

Many thanks in advance

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/insertbefore/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the selector for the n-th child of a given kind and the [`before`](http://api.jquery.com/before/) method (assuming your new content comes in `html`) :

```
$("#container > div:nth-of-type(42)").before(html);
```

If you want to insert a new element as the first or last child of a container, there is another api option:

```
$("#container").append( html );
$("#container").prepend( html );
```

(For the sake of completeness, [`append`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) / [`prepend`](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/) are the links into the jQuery API docs)

Comment: Hi @collapsar. Thanks for your reply. Before I take your suggestion as my way forward is there not anything like (the following is pretend/dreamed up jQuery): $("#container").insertAt( myHtml, 0 )

Comment: In fact it is: `$($("#container > div")[41]).before(html);` :-). Note the index shift, if you prefer to code this way (however, I honestly see no reason why that should be the case). Also note that wrapping the target element in another jQuery element comes handy in case the targeted position does not exist in the Dom.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add an element inside an other with jquery, you have to do like this :

```
$('#container').append(html);
```

Comment: Hi @loloMinou. Thank you for your reply. However append just puts the inserted content at the end of childlist.